# Problem in getting the output (language: Processing and Arduino IDE)

Tags: processing-lang

I am working on a small project with Processing and Arduino, in which, depending upon the value of a photoresistor, it displays whether it is day/night/evening.

I read the value from the photoresistor and write the value to the serial port. Then in Processing I read the value from the serial port and display depending on the value.

But I get a very flickery output, and there is always a -1 imprinted on the screen as shown in the video.

Please help me out.

[link to the video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5NnRFsbrHprNlJYYnBFcUNJQ3M)

**Code for Arduino:**

```
int ldr1 = A0;
int x,y;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ldr1,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  x = analogRead(ldr1);
  Serial.write(x);
  delay(100);
}
```

**Code for Processing:**

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;
int x,y;

void setup() {
  size(640, 320);
  port = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  x = port.read();
  text(x,100,100);
  if(x < 400 && x > 200) {
    textSize(32);
    fill(0,0,255);
    text("it is evening",200,200);
  }
  if(x < 200 && x > 20) {
    textSize(32);
    fill(0,255,0);
    text("it is night",200,200);
  }
  if(x > 400 && x < 900) {
    textSize(32);
    fill(255,0,0);
    text("it is morning",200,200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the Arduino actually on COM3? If serial read returns -1, then you did not receive a byte. You should check for if read >= 0 before entering your "if x < ... " etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for Serial::read() at https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_read_.html

it says:
*"Returns a number **between 0 and 255** for the next byte that's waiting in the buffer. **Returns -1 if there is no byte,** although this should be avoided by first cheacking available() to see if data is available."*

Either before calling "Draw" function, or inside "Draw", you should first check:

```
if(port.available()){
  //do your checking for X value and set text as you are doing before

}
```

IMPORTANT - you are only ever sending the lower byte (values 0-255) from Arduino when you do Serial.write(x). That is only 1 byte. The "int" return from an analogue read is 10 bits, and needs 2 bytes to store the information from 0-1023.

You should use the Arduino function Map() to scale it down from 0-1023 to 0-255. It looks like your application should be okay with this, in terms of resolution.

```
  int val = analogRead(ldr1);
  val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  Serial.write(val); //now you will not lose information
```

On the Processing side, you would then look at values from 0-255 to determine daylight/times of day.

Comment: Map is great if you need to do a linear interpolation but in a situation like this it's complete overkill. Rather than using map you could just divide the value by 4 or shift it right by 2 bits using 'val = val >> 2'. Either of these options are both far smaller and faster.

Comment: @Andrew you are correct, it's handy that it's a factor of 2 so shifting or division is fine.